# Crumpled Drywall At Ceiling - Wall Joint

Tags: drywall, walls, ceiling, painting, interior

I’ve noticed this defect in a few places where drywall wall meets ceiling. I don’t have crown mounding to cover it up.
[image]

[image]
Does anyone know what causes it?

Comment: I really can't see much deviation from ideal.

Comment: Are we talking about a little pucker on the wall? The tape was probably starved of mud and lifted on subsequent coats. Not a big deal. It might be easier said than done, but just don't look at it and it'll go away.

Comment: If just don't look at it does not help, try adding pictures or something to the wall away from it.

Comment: I’m fine leaving it as is, just wanted to make sure it wasn’t a sign of water damage etc..

Answer (score 1):

That's the paper used when it was taped.  I usually cut them out, sand, and use spackling when refilling the gaps.  Then you can texture to your heart's content.

If you are worried that it's a water leak, poke it with a thumbtack and see what you get.  I doubt that it is a leak, as it'd keep bulging and start leaking "somewhere," as well as cause the sheetrock to swell over time.